# How i can use \n (new character) to insert a blank line between each key-value pair in dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x

glossary = {
'docstring': 'it is a short form of documentation string.',
'title': 'it is form of just heading.'}

Print('glossary')

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html ?

Comment: I don't get it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Print the dictionary?

Comment: @PyxlDavon Then me neither?

Comment: I want to print each key-value pair in new line with blank   line in between each key-value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `pprint` library as [@don't talk just code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16759116/dont-talk-just-code) said.

It makes list, dictionary more readable

```py
import pprint
glossary = { 'docstring': 'it is a short form of documentation string.', 'title': 'it is form of just heading.'}

pprint.pprint(glossary)
```

Output

```py
{'docstring': 'it is a short form of documentation string.',
 'title': 'it is form of just heading.'}
```

You could use `str.replace` if you do not want to use a library.

```py
glossary = { 'docstring': 'it is a short form of documentation string.', 'title': 'it is form of just heading.'}

print( str(glossary).replace(",", ",\n") )
```

This makes the dictionary a string, and replace every comma `,` to a comma with a new line `,\n`.

This probably has a lot of limitation

Comment: I am beginner .  I want to use (\n) in my program so how i can use that.

Comment: You could do `print(str(glossary).replace(",", ",\n"))`

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you're lookikng for!

```
glossary = {'Lists': 'Used to store multiple items in a single variable.',
    'Tuples': 'Used  to store multiple values and can not be changed.',
    'If Statements': 'Decides whether certain statements need to be executed or not',
    'Strings': 'Surrounded by either single, or double quotation marks.',
    'Functions': 'A block of code which only runs when Its called'}

define = glossary['Lists'].title()
print(f"A List in Python is {define}.")
define = glossary['Tuples'].title()
print(f"\nA Tuple in Python is {define}.")
define = glossary['If Statements'].title()
print(f"\nAn If Statement in Python {define}.")
define = glossary['Strings'].title()
print(f"\n In Python a String is {define}.")
define = glossary['Functions'].title()
print(f"\nIn Python a Function is {define}.")
```